# The type Header is deprecated AsyncHttpResponseHandler()

Tags: java, android, asynchttpclient

I am Using AsyncHttpClient in all my projects. But recently I saw that type Header[] is Deprecated. Is it like I can no longer get Header[] in response ?

Is there any optional method that I can use ?

I am using **`android-async-http-1.4.6`** version

Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you found any solution? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just Update library to 1.4.9

`compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'`

Answer (score 1):

To make it work in 1.4.9 (not sure about earlier versions) version just replace the apache's `Header` import with `cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header`.

The same works for `StringEntity` (replace with  `cz.msebera.android.httpclient.entity.StringEntity`)